# Invoking ansible-playbook not working from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Attached images are the Ansible configuration screenshots [image]on Jenkins.Trying to invoke an ansible-playbook from Jenkins I get the below error:

```
[test-ansible-on-remote] $ sshpass ******** /usr/bin/ansible- 
playbook /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-ansible-on-remote/test.yml 
-i 40.68.3.120 -f 5 -u bmiadmin -k
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sshpass" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-ansible-on-remote"): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:466)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.CLIRunner.execute(CLIRunner.java:49)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AbstractAnsibleInvocation.execute(AbstractAnsibleInvocation.java:290)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookInvocation.execute(AnsiblePlaybookInvocation.java:31)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:261)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:232)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonito
```

Am I missing anything in the configuration?

Comment: Did you get workaround ?

Comment: Yes that's sorted. It needed sshpass to be installed as part of Jenkins docker image.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sshpass* needs to be installed as part of the host Jenkins docker image which Ansible uses for making the ssh connections to the hosts.